# How to create a listener for a forked process?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to create a pair of bash functions something along the lines of

```
function generator {
    while [ 1 -le 1 ]
    do
        # run log generator > somefile.log
    done
}

function tail_log {
    generator &
    tail -f somefile.log
}
```

So, I would run the command `tail_log` to see the log output. Except, instead of the infinite loop, I'd like allow the user to press `Q` to terminate the forked process.

So it looks like I need two things:

1. a way to get the process ID of a forked prcoess
2. a way to listen for user input so I can `kill` the process ID when the user presses `Q`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [`$!`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/shellvars)
2. Run `tail` in background as well. In foreground, use the [`read`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read) builtin. On input, kill both background processes.

   *While I'm at it:*
3. `while [ 1 -le 1 ]` → `while true` (see [somewhat related section](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#if_.5Bgrep_foo_myfile.5D) on BashPitfalls)
4. `function foo {...}` → `foo() {...}`  (see [deprecated syntax](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete) about this)